# cURL error: Failed to connect to xxxxxx(bucketname) port 80: Connection timed out (7)

Tags: yii2, alibaba-cloud

I am uploading a file to Alibaba Cloud - OSS bucket. Have correct access key and secret key.

Using oss-sdk-php through yii2, Getting Error

> {"name":"PHP Fatal Error","message":"Uncaught exception
>   'OSS\Core\OssException' with message 'RequestCoreException: cURL
>   resource: Resource id #351; cURL error: Failed to connect to
>   chinaproduct.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com port 80: Connection timed out
>   (7)'

Unable to get exact issue, any help would be appreciated.

```
    // #### Delete old files / Fetch all files with prefix
    $listObjectInfo = $ossClient->listObjects($productBucket,array('prefix'=>$uploadProductPrefix));
    $objectList = $listObjectInfo->getObjectList();
    foreach ($objectList as $objectInfo) {
        $fileNameToDelete = $objectInfo->getKey();
        $ossClient->deleteObject($productBucket,$fileNameToDelete);
        \Yii::info("OSS : Deleted file from OSS -$productBucket - $fileNameToDelete");
    }
} catch (OssException $e) {
    \Yii::info("OSS : Unable to delete old files from OSS $productBucket for dataId $dataId " . $e);
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this article related to alibaba connection timeout issue. Check this out. It may help you out https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/faq-detail/51471.htm

Comment: never used it , but you are getting timeout, which reminds me one of the posts recently went through my eyes where an IP from iran was not getting connected to the Google cloud, because google restrictions based on `from` and `to` ip and it does not allows IP addresses from iran, maybe your situation is similar, try `trraceout

Comment: Thank you. Seems like updating oss-sdk solved problem and I am able to upload files.